# How to constrain a Mathematica vector to a periodic domain?

Tags: periodic-function

Consider a function $F({\bf v})$, where ${\bf v}=(v_x,v_y)$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}_2$. I would like to define a new function $f({\bf v})$ which is periodic under $f({\bf v})=f({\bf v}+(n_x,n_y))$ for $n_{x,y}\in\mathbb{Z}$; but where $f({\bf v})=F({\bf v})$ for $0\le v_{x,y}<1$. In other words, I would like to force a Mathematica function `f[v]` to be equal to the value of `F[v]` in the domain of the $1\times 1$ torus.

Is there a simple and computationally efficient way to do this in Mathematica?

I know how to do this by first discretizing ${\bf v}$ into $N\times N$ points and defining the function ${\bf v}(m_x,m_y)=(\frac{m_x}{N},\frac{m_y}{N})$, for $m_{x,y}\in[1,N]$; where the condition $m_{x,y}\in[1,N]$ can be done via a modulus. However, I find this creates a lot of overhead, and requires predefining $N$. And if I wish to evaluate $F({\bf v})$ at some ${\bf v}$ not on the grid, I have to shift my grid, or refine a new one with a more convenient geometry.

For context, $F({\bf v})$ is a numerically calculated approximation of $f({\bf v})$, but where the approximation damages its periodicity in ${\bf v}$ for sufficiently large enough values of ${\bf v}$. However, since I only actually need $F({\bf v})$ for ${\bf v}$ defined in the first zone of the torus, I ignore the broken periodicity by defining $f({\bf v})$ as specified above. I'm just looking for a simple and efficient way to handle this bookkeeping.

Comment: Can't you just use `Mod` or `FractionalPart` ? `f[vec_] := F[FractionalPart[vec]]` would make `f[{1.2, 3.5}]` return `F[{0.2, 0.5}]` - or even more succinctly just define `f = F@*FractionalPart`

Comment: This is a nice solution for a square torus! I did not know about this function, and that it could take vectors as input. I would really love a more general solution which works for vector v defined in any geometry unit cell; however, I didn't really specify that in my question, so if you write an official response, I will declare it as the answer.

Comment: Just watch out for negative coordinates - FractionalPart won't work there - instead use `f=F[Mod[#,1]]&` to properly wrap them. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the simple case of a unit torus, define:

```
f = F@*FractionalPart;
```

Then for example: `f[{1.2, 3.5}]` would return the equivalent of `F[{0.2, 0.5}]`

This assumes your $\mathbf{v}$ are always in the upper right positive quadrant of the plane - `FractionalPart[-0.6]` will return `-0.6`.

Otherwise define `f = F[Mod[#, 1]] &` if you intend to supply negative coordinates. Now `f[{-0.6, 2.5}]` will return `F[{0.4,0.5}]` as expected.

If you need to shear/rotate/scale the torus, this is simple too. First represent the vector (e.g `{5.6,2.3}`) in the basis using an inverse - then take the result modulo 1:

```
basis = {{0, 2.5}, {1, 3}};
f[Mod[Inverse[basis] . {5.6, 2.3}, 1]]
(** {0.58, 0.24} - i.e f[{0.58 v1 + 0.24 v2} **)
```

You should compute the `Inverse` upfront to avoid calculating it over and over in any loops or plots you may have.

Comment: Ok, I know it's not kosher to leave comments like this but: This answer is awesome, and you are a total wizard. Thx

Comment: Just a minor correction. I found that I need to take the transpose of the inverse basis in order for this to work:
basis = {{0, 2.5}, {1, 3}};
f[Mod[Transpose@Inverse[basis]. {5.6, 2.3}, 1]]

Comment: @PaulEugenio It's convention in Mathematics to have the basis vectors be the columns of the basis matrix, so if you wanted to list them as rows that's why the transpose worked for you.